# how to use UILocationNotification in iPad?

Tags: iphone

In my universal application I m using the below code for UILocalNotification

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

```
    // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) 
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) 
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];

    // Set up the fire time
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    // Notification will fire in one minute
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
    [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    [dateComps release];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    // Notification details
    NSString *str = [txtfield_MyPills.text stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    NSString *str_Dosage = [txtfield_Dosage.text stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    NSString *str_Frequency = [txtfield_Frequency.text stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    NSString *str1 = [str stringByAppendingString:str_Dosage];
    NSString *strResult = [str1  stringByAppendingString:str_Frequency];
    localNotif.alertBody =strResult;;// [txtfield_MyPills text];//[eventText text];
    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";


    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
```

Its workin fine in iphone but if I run my application for iPad it shows that UilOcation is undeclared?

Please help me out and If u have sample code for UILocalNotification for iPad please give link for that

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

not available in 3.2 iOS

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

only available in 4.0 or later

Answer (score 0):

As Aron said Uiloaclnotifications are not available in 3.2.
As you might know the new version of iOs for iPad is coming very soon.
Asoming that it will take time until all users will upgrade you can do that -

Try this-

Class notifs = (NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification));

If (notifs != nil){

//the notification code here
}

I was informed by apple support that you can test that only on real devices that run 3.2  and not on the simulator.

You can look here in the mail composer code example at apple to see how they implemented that:

https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/iPad/index.html#samplecode/MailComposer/Listings/Classes_MailComposerViewController_m.html

Hope it will help
Shani